# como faço uma matriz NxN, sendo N uma variavel(adquirida no input), em python. Pois o exemplo abaixo nao consigo mudar os valores nos indices?

Tags: python, matriz

e1 = input().split()

e2 = input().split()

matri, numj = e1

nome, idj = e2

matriz = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] # nao consigo fazer a matriz que seja de escolha do usuario, ou seja uma variavel..

for l in range(0,3):

```
for c in range (0,3):
    matriz[l][c] = 0
```

for l in range(0,3):

```
for c in range(0,3):
    print(f'[{matriz[l][c]:^5}]',end='')    
print()
```

jg1 = input('Jogada 1:').split()
jgl, jgc = jg1
matriz[jgl][jgc]
print(matriz)

jg2 = input('Jogada 2:').split()
jgl2, jgc2 = jg2
print(jgl2)

nesse caso eu não estou conseguindo mudar um determinado indice. Por exemplo, quero mudar o inidice 2x1 de 0 para 2, eu nao consigo... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se queres mesmo usar listas, pode criar dois laçoes aninhados para adicionar sublistas dentros de outra lista e zeros dentro das sublistas.

```
N = input("Digite o valor de N: ")
N = int(N)

mat = []
for i in range(N):
    mat.append([])
    for j in range(N):
        mat[i].append(0)

print(mat)
```

Pra acessar e/ou modificar os índices, use `matriz[linha][coluna]` normalmente:

```
entrada = input("Digite os indices: ").split()
linha, coluna = entrada
linha = int(linha)
coluna = int(coluna)
print(f"Linha: {linha}")
print(f"Coluna: {coluna}")

entrada = float(input("Digite o novo valor: "))
mat[linha][coluna] = entrada

print(mat)
```

Espero ter ajudado. Se não, tente explicar melhor sua dúvida ;)

Comment: Muito Obrigado R.Pinho, deu certo, e era realmente o que eu precisava!!